# Pricing for AWS ECS container insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have enabled ECS container insights on my ECS cluster which has following configuration,

- 3 container Instances
- 2 ECS service (1 EC2, 1 Fargate)
- 6 ECS task(3 from ECS service, 3 from Fargate service).

It pushes a total of 56 metrics to ecs/ContainerInsights namespace.

Since there are custom metrics, does enabling ECS container insights also involve cost for call made to PutMetricData API?

If yes, how can I calculate the number of calls made?